# PM2 dev and prod environments on same server

Tags: node.js, pm2

I have a dev and prod instance of a microservice running on one machine. My ecosystem file gives them the same name. PM2 will not start the second instance when the first is running due to the name (presumably). Any ideas for a workaround here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the help... I ended up with this:

```
require("dotenv").config();

module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "app-" + process.env.environment,
      script: "./app.js",
      max_memory_restart: "150M"
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Hi Joe, did you find a good way pass different API keys to your prod/dev apps on one server?

Comment: @LukePighetti not super closely related to the original question, but how I do it is a check in encrypted .env files (prod.env.secure, staging.env.secure) and part of my process is decrypting those to just .env (prod.env.secure => .env)

Comment: am I to understand that the environment variables are scoped to the node process? I thought it was scoped to the operating system

Answer (score 0):

Pm2 do not sensitive filename because the name is usual for human not for PM2 process.

The usual mistake:

- Two script try to listen one port.
- conflict between scripts & resources.

The solution is start first process with pm2 and second process normal start with nodejs and you can see the log and error if not start, or started successfully then start second process first, first process second.

and you can use [pm2panel](https://github.com/4xmen/pm2panel) for easily add or remove process in pm2.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make separated config files for each environment.

**dev.config.js**:

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "dev-app",
      script: "./app.js",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "development"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

**prod.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "prod-app",
      script: "./app.js",
      env: {
        NODE_ENV: "production"
      }
    }
  ]
};
```

And then:

```
pm2 startOrRestart prod.config.js
pm2 startOrRestart dev.config.js
```

This approach [works](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3601) with `pm2 deploy` as well.